# What is causing this JS error - TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'panel.style')

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seem to be getting in over my head in terms of jQuery.

I'm experimenting with a simple accordion. As found below: https://jsfiddle.net/7h419wbo/

HTML

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

JS

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I transfer that exact code to my website, it doesn't seem to play nice with the rest of the JS on my page. Instead of the accordion panel opening, I get an error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'panel.style')

This is the rest of the JS I have on the page controlling a variety of things from my search bar, to back-to-to links etc...

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {

    $(function () {

        'use strict';

 $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('.scrollup').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });

// Change header size on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('#masthead').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('#masthead').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});

//slicknav

    $('#menu').slicknav({
    prependTo:'.slicknavbar', 
    allowParentLinks: 'true'
});

// search bar
$(function(){
  var $searchlink = $('#searchtoggl i');
  var $searchbar  = $('#searchbar');

  $('#searchandsocial ul li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).attr('id') == 'searchtoggl') {
      if(!$searchbar.is(":visible")) { 
        // if invisible we switch the icon to appear collapsable
        $searchlink.removeClass('fa-search').addClass('fa-search-minus');
      } else {
        // if visible we switch the icon to appear as a toggle
        $searchlink.removeClass('fa-search-minus').addClass('fa-search');
      }

      $searchbar.slideToggle(300, function(){
        // callback after search bar animation
      });
    }
  });

  $('.search-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
  });
});

/////



    });

})(jQuery, this);
```

What is it exactly that's causing the problem? and how should I adapt the JS of the accordion to fit in and play nice with everything else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the complete code with the panel code in it?

Comment: why toggle with JavaScript and not just CSS?  `.accordion + .panel { display: none; }  .accordion.active + .panel { display: block; }`

Comment: I'm following the W3C schools page here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp they use JavaScript

Comment: @Yathi that's not so easy. It's a Wordpress preview page I'm working on. I think I just dump all the individual CSS, JS, HTML in js fiddle it'll be a confused mess.

Comment: @C-M: I am mainly lookig for the js. But without looking at the code, I cannot tell you why you are getting the error.

Comment: @Yathi ok makes sense. I've created at test page on the website. Here's the link. Shame JSfiddle doesn't have a way to pull all the code direct from a page. http://www.cat.org.uk/snip/25089